# Draw scaled string in swing relative to rectangle

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, text-rendering

I need to place some geometrical primitives and texts, using `java.awt.Graphics2d`. If i scale them i expect that the relative position of elements to each other is scale-independent. Unfortunately if i just use `Graphics2D.scale(...)` to draw some Objects with `Graphics2D.drawRectangle(...)` and `Graphics2D.drawString(...)`the relative position changes. It's good to illustrate with this image:

[image]

So this is code, that produses this image:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Title");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new JPanel() {
            {
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 300));
            }

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                    doDraw(g2, i, i*10);
                }
            }

            void doDraw(Graphics2D g2, double scale, int yOffset) {
                String txt = "A-->                                                B";

                AffineTransform at = g2.getTransform();

                g2.scale(scale, scale);
                g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g2.drawRect(10, 10 + yOffset, 234, 20);
                g2.drawString(txt, 14, 24 + yOffset);

                g2.setColor(Color.red);
                g2.drawOval(228, 12 + yOffset, 14, 14);

                g2.setTransform(at);
            }
        });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see i the positions of elements is constant. The only thing that is changed is scale. At 100% the red circle is exactly on B-letter. But at 300% and more it's completly wrong. Am i doing something wrong or is it a bug in java? Is there any workaround for that issue?

The thing i want actually to achieve is, that at any scale the red circle is always painted around the letter "B".

**UPD:** I assume the reason why it happens, is how java renders scaled font. That's not just font, that is scaled like geometrical opereations, but for any scale java takes an apropriate dot size font. So Arial 8 at 75% is rendered just as Arial 6, not Arial 8 scaled down on 3/4. Otherweise scaled text would look auwful. But may be i am wrong with that.

**UPD 2**: tryed SwingUtilities2.drawText() - no effect.

**Background:** Actually i am making a sort of vector editing program. So i have objects in document, that have X, Y-coordiantes. So i just want to place them somehow in document. The problem is that by changing zoom, the objects "jumps" at they relative positions to each other. So if i want to make some text like CHECKED and make letter C being in a box/circle, it depends on scale.

Comment: Also note that the position of "B" is highly dependent on the font metrics. You rely on it being exactly the same on every platform.

Comment: @kiheru if two machines using exactly one font file, it should be the same... or not?

Comment: Java fonts do not scale linearly due to the handling of fractional width of characters such as spaces. Another approach you can try is drawing at a fixed standard size to a separate BufferedImage, then performing scale operations on it.

Comment: I'm not certain about that. OpenJDK uses freetype for font rasterization, but the Oracle branded JDK probably uses something else, so there could be differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set also `RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS` to `ON` for the `Graphics` instance

Comment: Unfortunately no effect

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AMR Fractional metrics *does* fix the issue for me (to the degree it can be fixed without proper calculation of the string length). Looks like an answer to me; that it apparently does not work for OP is a different issue.

Comment: @kiheru youre right. It got marked as low quality and it appeared to be a poor answer. Perhaps if the author of this answer expanded more it wouldn't have gotten flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with `g.getFontMetrics(font)` in order to compute the right size for the font.

Comment: But what should i do with this metrics? I have two objects, with (x, y) positions. And i want that they look exactly same at any scale. It works fine for geometrical primitives, but not for text.